# SQL - Transaction update 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form that requires a user to validate their email address, the link is sent to the user as

`http://app.myurl.org/h/activate.php?email=useremail%40gmail.com&key=80fddb7fa21dd2e2639ae5ec82b9d511&api=8a2d01d7411ec2488307744ddf070a4d`

The user is directed to the activate page.

I am trying to get the `email`, `key`, and `api` from the url. I am then trying to update both the users table and the roster table.

Rosters table columns update is `Activation`
Users table columns to update is `groups`
They both pass the unique value of a MD5 random hash as an `API KEY` throughout the website. Everything is working smooth, just not the query.

Any ideas where I went wrong?

```
    <?php
include ('dbcon.php');
if (isset($_GET['email']) && preg_match('/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)+$/',
     $_GET['email'])) {
     $email = $_GET['email'];
    }
    if (isset($_GET['key']) && (strlen($_GET['key']) == 32))
     //The Activation key will always be 32 since it is MD5 Hash
     {
     $key = $_GET['key'];
    }
    if (isset($_GET['api']) && (strlen($_GET['api']) == 32))
     //The API key will always be 32 since it is MD5 Hash
     {
     $API = $_GET['api'];
    }
    if (isset($email) && isset($key)) {

     // Update the database to set the "activation" field to null

     $query_activate_account = "BEGIN TRANSACTION; 
                                UPDATE table_roster SET Activation=NULL WHERE(email ='$email' AND Activation='$key')LIMIT 1;
                                UPDATE table_users SET groups=[99] WHERE(pinAPP_API ='$API') LIMIT 1;
                                COMMIT";
     $result_activate_account = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_activate_account);

     // Print a customized message:
     if (mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) == 1) //if update query was successful
     {
     echo '<div>You may now proceed.</div>';

     } else {
     echo '<div>Oops !You could not be validated. Please recheck the link or contact your hiring manager.</div>';

     }

     mysqli_close($dbc);

    } else {
     echo '<div>An Error Occurred.</div>';
    }
    ?>
```

I did some searching on SO about updating two tables with one transaction and it was recommended to use `BEGIN TRANSACTION; UPDATE... UPDATE... COMMIT;` however I am getting a failure and my predefined error message is `An Error Occurred`

Comment: *An Error Occurred* is defined by you. The true cause of showing this message is, `isset($email) && isset($key)` return false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up with the following

```
if (isset($email) && isset($key)) {
    mysqli_query($dbc);
    $verified = mysqli_query($dbc,"
       UPDATE tbl_users t1, tbl_roster t2 SET t1.groups='[22]', t2.prescreen='0' WHERE t1.API='$API' AND t2.API='$API' AND t2.prescreen='$key';
    ");
    if ($verified !== false) {
        mysqli_query($dbc);
        echo '<br><center><div class="success"></div>';

    } 
    else {
        mysqli_query($dbc);
        echo '<br><div class="validation"></div>';
    }
    mysqli_close($dbc);
  } else {
    echo '<br><div class="error">An Error Occurred.</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use [mysqli_multi_query](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_multi_query.asp) instead of `mysqli_query`.

Also you must start the transaction and commit or rollback it with separate queries.

```
mysqli_query($dbc, "START TRANSACTION");

$result_activate_account = mysqli_multi_query(
    $dbc,
    "UPDATE table_roster SET Activation=NULL WHERE (email ='$email' AND Activation='$key') LIMIT 1;
     UPDATE table_users SET groups=[99] WHERE (pinAPP_API ='$API') LIMIT 1;"
);

if ($result_activate_account !== false) {
    mysqli_query($dbc, "COMMIT");

    echo '<div>You may now proceed.</div>';
} else {        
    mysqli_query($dbc, "ROLLBACK");

    echo '<div>Oops !You could not be validated. Please recheck the link or contact your hiring manager.</div>';
}
```

Comment: I get a defined error now `Oops !You could not be validated. Please recheck the link or contact your hiring manager.`

Comment: You can see what errors were thrown when executing the query. Please note that the first update query has some missing spaces.. after WHERE and before LIMIT.. try fixing that to see if the query is successfully executed

Comment: Right before `echo` in the `else` statement

Comment: `if (mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) == 1) //if update query was successfull
 {
 echo '<div>You may now proceed.</div>';

 } else {
  mysqli_error($dbc);
 echo '<div>Oops !You could not be validated. Please recheck the link or contact your hiring manager.</div>';

 }

 mysqli_close($dbc);

} else {
 echo '<div>An Error Occurred.</div>';
}`@MateiMihai

Comment: I've just updated my answer.. you cannot use `mysqli_affected_rows` when using `mysqli_multi_query`. Instead of that, you can check if `mysqli_multi_query` returns `false` meaning that the query failed

Comment: Also, you can use `mysqli_error($dbc);` to debug but you must `var_dump` it or simply `echo` the result.. such as `echo mysqli_error($dbc);`

Comment: Getting error `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TRANSACTION; UPDATE wrightway_roster SET Activation=NULL WHERE (email ' at line 1`

Comment: Also, using Native 5.4 php

Comment: I've updated the answer.. you can try it like that.. you should separate the transaction statements from the updates.. You must check if the result is ok and to commit or rollback depending of the result value..

Comment: Getting this now. I'll update my OP with my provisions. Oops !You could not be validated. Please recheck the link or contact your hiring manager.

Comment: Okay,l I got it to work. However, its only updating the roster table, and not updating the users table groups column.

Comment: try separate update queries with `mysqli_query` and verify both results with `mysqli_affected_rows`.. You can verify the error thrown for the second query like you did before

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use multiple queries at once. mysqli provides functions for transactions, they only work with MySQL 5.6 and above though:

```
 mysqli_begin_transaction($dbc);
 mysqli_query($dbc, "UPDATE table_roster SET Activation=NULL WHERE(email ='$email' AND Activation='$key')LIMIT 1");
 mysqli_query($dbc, "UPDATE table_users SET groups=[99] WHERE(pinAPP_API ='$API') LIMIT 1");
 mysqli_commit($dbc);
```

Also, take a look at prepared statements and bind those values instead of using them directly.

Comment: Quote: `Requires MySQL 5.6 and above, and the InnoDB engine`; What's your MySQL version, and what database type are you using?

Comment: This option won't help you then. I'll leave it here though, it may help other people.